# Deploy an app privately to Heroku

Tags: heroku, paas, cloudbees

Our current platform provider allows us to set deployed apps to private, which protects access to an app behind a log-in screen. This is great for deploying development versions of our website behind a wall for testing on the internet. Is there a feature or plug-in that can provide similarity on the Heroku platform? I know we could code our own...but we'd love to get away with relying on the provider for this.

Thanks,
Siegfried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

I've always had to implement my own solution. For Ruby/Rack-based apps I usually implement `Rack::Auth::Basic` based on the `RACK_ENV`. That way I can easily turn off the authentication when the app goes to production.

For Node.js, I do the same environment check, and use Connect's `basicAuth` middleware.